# (C#) How to fill a 2D array with 2 different numbers evenly, but randomly?

Tags: c#, random, multidimensional-array

For a randomized tic-tac-toe game simulator, I need to utilize a 2D array to simulate a round between 2 players.  To fill the array, I've been using a simple randomizer to generate a random number between 0 and 1.

```
    //create 2D array
  const int ROWS = 3;
  const int COLS = 3;
  int[,] tictactoeArray = new int[ROWS, COLS];
   //create random variable
  Random rand = new Random();

   //method to fill array with random values between 0 and 1.
  private void RandomizeArray(ref int[,] iArray)
  {
      for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
      {
          for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
          {
              tictactoeArray[row, col] = rand.Next(2);
          }
      }
  }
```

But when I use a random number generator like this, I occasionally end up with an impossible combination of values in relation to tic-tac-toe.  As in the value 1 will occur 6 or more times, and make the game unfair for the other "player".  I've done extensive searching, but haven't found a way to (more or less) evenly distribute the 2 values.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems simpler just to pre-create the x's and o's in a 1 dimensional array and then randomly shuffle them like so

```
            //Both X and O always get at least 4 moves
            List<int> common = new List<int> { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

            //Either X or O gets a 5th move, make this equally likely
            Random rand = new Random();
            common.Add(rand.Next(0, 2));

            //Randomly shuffle the X's and O's, this creates a completed tic tac toe board
            //This can have more than one winner since we aren't stopping when someone wins
            //as would normally be done
            var randomBoard = common.OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).ToArray();

            //Convert to a 2 dimensional array if desired
            int[,] twoDRandomBoard = new int[3, 3];
            for (int i = 0; i < randomBoard.Length; i++)
                twoDRandomBoard[i / 3, i%3] = randomBoard[i];
```

You will end up with some boards having two "winners", but this is the way it has to be if you assume the entire board is full which is what you are showing in your question. If you want to stop once someone wins then that will be different, but this will work for a random complete board.

Comment: That is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for!  I know this won't check for a winner, but I hope that this will pass muster for a checkoff.  If not, I can get advice from my instructor afterwards.  Using a 1 dimensional array might be bending the rules a bit, but it's worth it for having a functional program.

Answer (score 2):

You need to simulate the turns of player. instead of randomly generating 1 or 2, you can follow the below algorithm  only assume

```
0. initialize all 9 positions with 0  on tic-tac-toe board
1. select a number between 0 to 8 randomly. ( which denotes one of 9 positions)
2. put 1 in that position
3. select another number  between 0 to 8 randomly ( if it collides with number previously selected pull other  random number.  
4. put 2 in that position. 
5. repeat till all the  9 positions are filled.
```

Approach 2 ..

```
create a Linked list of 9 numbers (from 1 to 9). 
draw a number (name it x) between 1 to size of the Set ( which will be 9 for first draw)
read the value at the  position 'x' and put 1 in that position 
remove the element at position x
draw another number x ( between 1 to 8 this time ) and put 2 in that position.
remove the element at position x.
keep doing till linked list is empty.
```

Comment: Note that for realistic tic-tac-toe there should be win check after 2 and 4.

Comment: These approaches do the trick!  But my limited C# coding experience is making it difficult to get them to work...

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to the question title would be something like this:

```
var random = new Random();
var randomValues = new[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 } // enough values to fill board
    .Select(x => new { Weight = random.Next(), Value = x }) // add random weight
    .OrderBy(x => x.Weight) // order by weight to create random sort
    .Take(9) // only need 9 of the 10 values
    .ToList();
var ticTacToeBoard = new int[3, 3];
var index = 0;
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) // fill the two-dimensional array
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
    {
        ticTacToeBoard[row, column] = randomValues[index].Value;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Most of the time, this "random without replacement" technique will result in a possible ending game board, however, you'll occasionally get a game board with 3 zeroes *and* 3 ones in a row, which would not be valid. To solve that, you could put the above code in a loop and only exit the loop in the case of a valid game board.

That said, I agree that @meetthakkar's approach to actually simulate a game would more sense for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I might be a little confused but it doesn't make sense to have a tic-tac-toe board represented with 1 or 0 being populated from that start, maybe 1 or 2.

Would recommend doing the following :

```
private static ThreadLocal<Random> rand = new ThreadLocal<Random>(()=>new Random());

const int PLAYER_ONE = 1;
const int PLAYER_TWO = 2;

//color decided by who goes first in tic-tac-toe?
private static int playingColor;

private static void PlayRound(int[][] board)
{
    var playableCoords = new List<Tuple<int,int>>();

    for(int x=0;x<board.Length;x++)
        for(int y=0;y<board[x].Length;y++)
            if(board[x][y] == 0)
                playableCoords.Add(Tuple.Create(x,y));

    //check for a terminal board state before you do this method
    if(!playableCoords.Any()) return;

    var randm = rand.Value;

    var vl = playableCoords[ randm.Next(playableCoords.Count - 1) ];

    board[vl.Item1][vl.Item2] = playingColor ;
}
```

There are more efficient ways to do this, if you were dealing with a board with a lot of possible combinations then I would suggest keeping a record of available spots and taking from there, but for a 3x3 game don't see the need to do that.

If you want to do this until it is full just do this :

```
var board = new int[3][3];
for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
{ 
    playingColor = (i%1)+1;
    PlayRound(board);
}
```

Doesn't really make sense to me but that is how you would simulate a game.

Answer (score 0):

```
void RandomizeArray(ref int[,] iArray)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                tictactoeArray[row, col] = rand.Next(2);
            }
        }
    }
```

please put `Random rand = new Random()` into the funcion body.
Maybe better every times it make a new  rand .